# Determine if more posts are available than was asked for in `query_posts()`?

Tags: query-posts

I'm getting products (from a specific category) using a custom `query_posts()` function. I limited the `showposts` parameter to 25, so how do I know to activate pagination if there are still products (posts) to load?

My `query_posts()` code looks as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'term' => $idObj->slug, // category slug
    'showposts' => 25,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'paged' => $paged  // global $paged variable
);

$all_products = query_posts( $args );
```

And then I output my products using a `foreach` statement:

```
foreach ($all_products as $product) {...}
```

I put this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1588311/104874) in my **functions.php**, but `$paged` nor `$max_pages` don't seem to be set. So I get `false` from this function.

Now, can anyone maybe point me in some direction, as I've got no clue.

Comment: I guess `showposts` is deprecated... You should use `posts_per_page`...

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> First of all: do not use `query_post`!
>
> For more information read: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Use the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class to fetch your products, also pay attention that the `showposts` argument is deprecated, use `posts_per_page` instead:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'term' => $idObj->slug, // category slug
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'paged' => $paged  // global $paged variable
);

$all_products = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $all_products->have_posts() ) : $all_products->the_post();
    // do stuff here...
endwhile;

// Reset $post global
wp_reset_postdata();
```

To get the total number of found posts use the `$found_posts` property. And if you need the total amount of pages use the `$max_num_pages` property.

```
$found_posts = $all_products->found_posts;
$max_pages = $all_products->max_num_pages;
```

Comment: The correct reset function for a custom query via a new `WP_Query` object is [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata). Refer to the codex or to Rarst's flowchart you linked to. *Fixed*. Also, while I was at it, note that "fields of query" are properties.